# Use of ToTitleCase

Tags: c#

I wonder if anyone can help, I am trying to change something from caps to lower case with the Caps first letter, I undertsand I can use ToTitleCase - but I'm struggling to get this going;

```
 <%= Html.Label("rblDeposit." + (i + 1).ToString(), item.Text.ToLowerInvariant())%>
```

I understand I need to supply a string into the ToTitleCase, but how do I do apply this to item.text part ?

I thought I could do something like this;

```
<%= Html.Label("rblDeposit." + (i + 1).ToString(), item.Text.ToTitleCase(item.Text))%>
```

Thanks

Comment: hmm - the documentation for this method says "We reserve the right to make this API slower in the future" !!

Answer (score 13):

If you do not want to use the current CultureInfo, you can use the static InvariantCulture:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(item.Text)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, the page does work with this, however before I was using ToLowerInvariant to change it to lower case, and now everything is upper case - how could I reintroduce the ToLowerInvariant into this - the data being pulled is upper case. Thanks

Comment: In my understanding, TitleCase works if there are spaces in the input text. It capitalizes the first character of each word. You should not have to "lower" the case first before converting to TitleCase. - I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: ToTitleCase very likely doesn't touch non-first letters of words.  Rather than passing `item.Text` to `ToTitleCase`, pass `item.Text.ToLower()` or `item.Text.ToLowerInvariant()`.

Comment: It's better to use CurrentCulture than InvariantCulture.

Answer (score 8):

[`ToTitleCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) is defined in the [`TextInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.aspx) class, that you can reach through the current [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx):

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(item.Text)
```

Answer (score 2):

[ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) is a method of TextInfo, not Text. Get a TextInfo from a [CultureInfo.TextInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.textinfo.aspx); in particular, try `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo`.