# .ToTitleCase not working on all upper case string

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

```
Public Function TitleCase(ByVal strIn As String)
      Dim result As String = ""
      Dim culture As New CultureInfo("en", False)
      Dim tInfo As TextInfo = culture.TextInfo()
      result = tInfo.ToTitleCase(strIn)
      Return result
 End Function
```

If I input "TEST" into the function above. The output is "TEST".  Ideally it would output "Test"

I also tried the code snippets from this post to no avail:  [Use of ToTitleCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716030/use-of-totitlecase)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If memory serves, [**ToTitleCase()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) never seemed to work for all capitalized strings. It basically requires you to convert the string to lowercase prior to processing.

**From the MSDN:**

> Generally, title casing converts the first character of a word to
>   uppercase and the rest of the characters to lowercase. However, **this
>   method does not currently provide proper casing to convert a word that
>   is entirely uppercase**, such as an acronym.

**Workaround Usage (in C#):**

```
string yourString = "TEST";

TextInfo formatter = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;    
formatter.ToTitleCase(yourString.ToLower());
```

Comment: To add to your great answer, it's also worth noting that you can simply do: `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(myString.ToLower());` rather than creating multiple objects.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, that seemed liked a long string to put in, and I cannot stand scroll-bars in my code blocks :)

Comment: @JamieDixon If you are unhappy with a `new CultureInfo` instance each time you reach such code, you can use `formatter = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").TextInfo;` instead. This gets the _same_ cached object each time. That object does not "use user override" (`UseUserOverride`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I don't think I mind. It's been 7 years and a lot has happened :)

Answer (score 2):

Also String.ToTitleCase() will work for most strings but has a problem with names like McDonald and O'Brian, and I use CurrentCulture for variations in capitalization. This is a simple extension method that will handle these:

```
public string ToProperCase(this string value)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        return "";
    }

    string proper = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
                    TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value.ToLower());

    int oddCapIndex = proper.IndexOfAny({
        "D'",
        "O'",
        "Mc"
    });


    if (oddCapIndex > 0) {
        // recurse
        proper = proper.Substring(0, oddCapIndex + 2) +
                 proper.Substring(oddCapIndex + 2).ToProperCase();

    }

    return proper;

}
```

Also the IndexOfAny(String[]) extension:

```
public int IndexOfAny(this string test, string[] values)
{
    int first = -1;
    foreach (string item in values) {
        int i = test.IndexOf(item);
        if (i > 0) {
            if (first > 0) {
                if (i < first) {
                    first = i;
                }
            } else {
                first = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding answer 1, it's a nice idea but the code does not compile;  and, when corrected for syntax, it does not work.  I didn't have time to debug it but you will need to if you want to use it.  Part of the problem is the index assumes 1-based indexes but they are 0-based in C#.  There are other issues, as well.